# XPATH expression with negating condition in SAP PI XSLT Mapping

Tags: xpath, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have to maintain conditions in Interface Determination of ICO in SAP PI. I have several invoice types like L1, S1, G1, F1, etc. I have two separate mappings as per requirement.

When the Invoice type is L1, S1 or G1, and LAND1 = IND, PARW= W and QUALF=015, I want to pick 1st mapping and for remaining invoice types I want to pick 2nd mapping.

The XPath expressions in the Condition Editor for the two mappings are:

1)

```
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW = 'W' and LAND1 = 'IND'])   EX   AND
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF = 015 and ORGID = 'L1'])    EX   OR
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW = 'W' and LAND1 = 'IND'])   EX   AND 
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF = 015 and ORGID = 'G1'])    EX   OR 
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW = 'W' and LAND1 = 'IND'])   EX   AND
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF = 015 and ORGID = 'S1'])    EX
```

2) (I have an issue with the second line about ORGID expression)

```
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW = 'W' and LAND1 = 'IND'])                                    EX AND
(/ZEINV_INVOIC02/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF = 015 and ( ORGID ≠ 'L1' or ORGID ≠ 'G1' or ORGID ≠ 'S1' )]) EX
```

The issue is that when the ICO is run, it is picking both mappings, satisfying both conditions with these values:

```
ORGID = 'L1'
QALF  = 015
PARW  = 'W' 
LAND1 = 'IND'
```

What is the XPath expression for the second condition when we have ORGID values other than L1, G1 and S1?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the expression `ORGID ≠ 'L1' or ORGID ≠ 'G1' or ORGID ≠ 'S1'` is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)), i.e. it's true if `ORGID` is `'L1'` and true if `ORGID` is not `L1`, so the whole expression is always true whatever the value of `ORGID` is.

What you want is this:

```
not( ORGID = 'L1' or ORGID = 'G1' or ORGID = 'S1' )
```

Note that you may also use the equivalent expression without `not`, by using the [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), here you have to switch and/or and negate the conditions:

```
ORGID != 'L1' and ORGID != 'G1' and ORGID != 'S1'
```

NB: does `≠` really work? Shouldn't you use `!=`?